# Dialyzer does not know :httpc

Tags: elixir, dialyzer

I am working on Elixir, using Erlang built-in `:httpc` function to perform a get request.

```-elixir
if {:ok, {status, header, body}} = :httpc.request(:get, {img, []}, [], []) do
  # ...
end
```

The functions are working well. Then after running mix dialyzer, it returns errors:

```-elixir
:0:unknown_function
Function :httpc.request/4 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
lib/vutuv/accounts.ex:301:guard_fail
Guard test:
_ :: {:ok, {_, _, _}}

===

false

can never succeed.
________________________________________________________________________________
done (warnings were emitted)
```

I put this line to tell Dialyzer to skip checking the function.

```-elixir
@dialyzer {:nowarn_function, get_gravatar: 2}
```

However, the error still persists

```-elixir
:0:unknown_function
Function :httpc.request/4 does not exist.
________________________________________________________________________________
done (warnings were emitted)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is solved in https://elixirforum.com/t/dialyzer-does-not-know-httpc/21622/3

After adding `:inets` to the `extra_applications` in `mix.exs`, everything is passed successfully.

Comment: Unrelated but important: :httpc doesn't do https (well it does, but not automatically and it's hard to get it right even for security experts) so be careful should you need either authentication, integrity or confidentiality when doing requests.